# "self = @" の "@" はどういう意味ですか？

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

CoffeeScriptで書かれたjQueryプラグインを読んでいるのですが、@の記述がよくわかりません。下記のような使われ方をしているのですが、これは何を表しているのでしょうか。

```
self = @
```

また、@はJavascript、jQueryにおいてどんな意味を持ちますか？
本で探しても@に関する記述がなく困っています。

Comment: 編集メモ：元の質問では「jsのプラグイン」と書かれていましたが、恐らくjQueryプラグインのことだろうと思い書き換え、それ以外の「js」を「Javascript」としました。また原題は「jqueryの"@"に関して」でしたが、質問文からして実際にはjQueryだけでなくJSのキーワードという線も疑っていたようなので、題名からjQueryへの言及を取り除きました。

Answer (score 9):

[本家サイト](http://coffeescript.org/) の説明の
**All together now:**
の対比表の部分で、

> ```
> CoffeeScript  JavaScript
> @, this          this
> ```

になっているので、JavaScriptで言う`this`を表す（同じと考えていい）ようです。
*As a shortcut for this.property, you can use @property.*
という説明があるので、
`this.property`を`@property`のように書くためのショートカットのようです。

Comment: All together now: という記述はページ内に二か所ありますが、 [Operators and Aliases](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) の箇所ですね。

Answer (score 3):

JavaScriptは何処から呼び出したかによって同じ文脈でもthisの意味が変化します。
CoffeeScriptでは@を使う事でthisのタイプ数を減らす以外にもかっこいい使い方が出来ます。

例えばこんなことしたい場合です。

```
hoge = function() {
  var foo;
  this.piko = 123
  foo = function() {
    return this.piko
  }
}
```

この時上で宣言した`pikoプロパティ`は`foo関数`の中では使う事が出来ません。
どうしても使いたい場合は、少々小細工が必要になります。

```
hoge = function() {
  var self = this;
  var foo;
  this.piko = 123;
  foo = function() {
    return self.piko
  }
};
```

コレを実現する為にCoffeeScriptで書くとこうなります。

```
hoge = ->
  @piko = 123
  foo = =>
    @piko
```

この時thisを無名関数の中に持って入りたい時は、
`=>`で関数定義するだけで２つ目のような迂回するJavaScriptを生成することが出来ます。
（これは似たような仕様がES6で採用されたかと思います）

Comment: `@piko` の代わりに `this.piko` と書いても同じように使えますね： https://jsfiddle.net/9yupbucv/

Comment: へー！そうなんですね！…URLありがとうございます。今CoffeeScriptの公式サイトで確認もしましたがthisと@で全く同じJSが吐き出されることも確認しました。ありがとうございます、勉強になりました！